# Hardware Specification of Server for Cassandra Service

Tags: facebook, cassandra

I want to know about H/W and memTable size with respect to Cassandra.
I read article about Cassandra.
Title of the article is "A Decentralized Structured Storage System".
In this article, FaceBook is using Cassandra to store about +50TB of data on a 150 node cluster and it's operated for 100 million person in 2008 year.
But I want to know about detail H/W Specification.

e.g:

```
1. we use SMP processor for each node. (Intel dual-core server : frequency --> 1.5GHz)
2. we use 4G RAM size per node.
3. we use 128Gbyte SSD Hard per node.
4. we use 1G switching ethernet.
5. we use (which) L4 switch for Gateway Load-balancing.
```

And

- I want to know how much memTable size do you use in FaceBook when you operate Cassandra for any Application.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is relative Hardware agnostic. So you can run it on commodity hardware.
But if you plan to maximize throughput, your configuration could be better.

- Use SSD for CommitLog
- Use RAID 0 o kinds of it for SSTables
- Take more RAM for caches. 16, 32 and more GB.
- 1G switch might be enough.
- And of cause Cassandra scales best (linear scalable)! Use more nodes and good drivers.

Every performance consideration should begin with real scenarion.
Start and profile your system a little.

PS: [Hardware Requirenments in the Docu](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware)